# WordPress turn Gallery into Slideshow - Multiple Slideshows per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I used the code from [Reference link](http://www.paddsolutions.com/turn-wordpress-gallery-into-slideshow/) to allow users to create a slideshow from the built in gallery feature in WP. The issue I have found is that when a user creates more than one slide show on a page the two conflict with each other.

```
function create_slideshow() {

// Remove the HTML tags generated in the gallery.
jQuery('.single-format-gallery style').remove();
jQuery('.gallery p').remove();

// Wrap the gallery.
jQuery('.gallery').wrap('<div id="divSlideshow" class="box_slideshow gallery-wrap">');

// Add the slideshow controller.
jQuery('.gallery-wrap').append('<div id="divSlideshow_Nav" class="box_nav"><span id="jqc-pages"></span></div>');

// Add the controls.
//  jQuery('#slideshow-controller').prepend('<button class="dir-button dir-button-l" id="jqc-prev" href="#">Prev</button>');
//  jQuery('#slideshow-controller').append('<button class="dir-button dir-button-r" id="jqc-next" href="#">Next</button>');

jQuery('.gallery').cycle({
    fx                : 'fade',
    speed             : 1000,
    timeout           : 3000,
    cleartypeNoBg     : true,
    activePagerClass  : 'activeSlide',
    pager             : '#jqc-pages',
    prev              : '#jqc-prev',
    next              : '#jqc-next',
    pause             : true,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index,elem) {
        return '<button class="" id="jqc-button-' + index + '" value="' + index + '"><span>' + (index+1) + '</span></button>';
    }
});
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.noConflict();
create_slideshow();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change all of the elements being set with an ID to be set with a class instead, that should resolve conflicts because the ID selector should be used to specify a single, unique element.

```
jQuery('.gallery-wrap').each(function(){
  var control = '';
  $(this).append(control);
});
```

Where you have the `var control` set to the controller you want to append

Comment: I updated the ID's and that has helped, however the buttons are the second issue.

    `jQuery('.gallery-wrap').append('<div id="divSlideshow_Nav" class="box_nav"><span id="jqc-pages"></span></div>');`

How do I add the correct .each to increment them correctly. Right now all the buttons display in the first slide show.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, do you mean something like this? (Putting it in my original comment so it's legible)

Answer (score 0):

I had to completly rewrite the js as the buttons were not going into the correct div and each div was not assigned its own id.

function create_slideshow() {

```
// Remove the HTML tags generated in the gallery.
jQuery('.single-format-gallery style').remove();
jQuery('.gallery p').remove();

// Wrap the gallery.
jQuery('.gallery').each(function(i,elm){
    jQuery(this).wrap('<div id="divSlideshow-'+i+'" class="box_slideshow gallery-wrap">').after('<div id="divSlideshow_Nav-'+i+'" class="box_nav"><span class="jqc-pages"></span></div>');

    jQuery(this).cycle({
        fx                : 'fade',
        speed             : 1000,
        timeout           : 3000,
        cleartypeNoBg     : true,
        activePagerClass  : 'activeSlide',
        pager             : '#divSlideshow_Nav-'+i+' .jqc-pages',
        prev              : '#divSlideshow_Nav-'+i+' #jqc-prev',
        next              : '#divSlideshow_Nav-'+i+' #jqc-next',
        pause             : true,
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index,elem) {
            return '<button class="" id="jqc-button-' + index + '" value="' + index + '"><span>' + (index+1) + '</span></button>';
        }
    });

}); 

}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.noConflict();
create_slideshow();
});
```